# How is a Crunchbase organisation's address flagged as headquarters?

Tags: companies, address

A [Crunchbase registered user](https://www.crunchbase.com/app/register) can add addresses to an existing organisation. These addresses can be named freely (e.g. "HQ", "Headquarters", "xyz", etc.) via a free-form field, but the address creation form does not include a *headquarter* flag.

However, at the other end of Crunchbase, the API gives access to a one-to-one relationship between organizations and headquarter addresses (alongside a one-to-many relationship between organizations and all their addresses), according to [this page](https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/organization).

As a user of the API, I have personally been able to verify that the organization HQ file is a subset of the organization address file and that there is no more than one HQ per organization.

So, somewhere between the user interface and the API, addresses are flagged as HQs. How are organization addresses flagged as HQ and by whom? Have I missed something in the Crunchbase user interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. The first address added to a company in Crunchbase is assigned the headquarter relationship. If a new HQ is subsequently added, it can be selected and reset on crunchbase.com on the top card.